# Ajax from richfaces messing with my css style

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using richfaces to get some nice features but styling those aren't quite easy.
I'm using JSF validator in order to highlight invalid fields,

problem is the "style" parameter is not working with richfaces tags, even if I add '!important'.

JSF code :

```
                            <rich:calendar value="#{creerPersonne1.dateNaissance}"
                                locale="FR/fr" popup="true" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                showApplyButton="true" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" required="true"
                                style="#{component.valid ? 'width:200px;' : 'border-color:red !important;border-width:2px !important;width:200px !important;'}"/>
```

As you can see the CSS is there but it must be overwritten by something

[image: style ignored]

Any of you ever had this problem?
Thanks

Comment: It's tough to see if it's really those styles being overwritten or something else that just visually obfuscates the element-in-question.  If you put it in a fiddle, it's easier to help.

Comment: fiddle? (I'm guessing it's not violon)